# How can I overwrite a list from a template that has related lists

Tags: 2010, list, list-template

I have a list in our QA environment that I need to copy to my local dev environment.  I've copied the template from QA, and tried deleting the list in my dev.  I got an error saying that it has a related list.  Is there a workaround for this, aside from manually adding columns?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the column that had the lookup associated with it.  You should then be able to remove the list.